# How to connect to "alt.os.linux.ubuntu" newsgroup

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, gnome

I want to access the `alt.os.linux.ubuntu` newsgroup and read the threads. I appreciate if someone could tell me how to add this newsgroup. I downloaded PAN, but they are asking for server names for connecting.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a newsreader, but now you need a newsgroup server.  In the "old" days, lots of ISPs included access to newsgroup servers for free, but those days appear to be over.  You'll need to buy access to such a server, unfotunately.  I can't tell you which is best, but this link ([newsgroups](http://www.slyck.com/Newsgroups_Guide_NewsServers)) will explain how it works and give you links to lots of servers.

Most are not very expensive, but there are different levels of service for different rates so you'll have to evaluate your needs and decide what you need.

It's much like getting a web browser for free, but you still have to pay for Internet access.  The browser doesn't really give you access to the web, just the ability to "read" the web once you've obtained access.

Comment: thanks, that helped. I thought alt.os.linux.ubuntu could be accessed for free! well, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think **alt.os.linux.ubuntu** 
 is no more available. Check the Google groups. They stopped showing Ubuntu on the list. https://groups.google.com/groups/dir?sel=&q=alt.os.linux&start=0&hl=en&

Comment: Still exists as of 7 May 2015. Using eternal september.

Comment: And still available August 29th 2019 :)